# Como usar thread em JavaFX?

Tags: thread, javafx

Antes de aparecer o cenário principal da minha aplicação JavaFX, quero que apareça uma classe contendo uma apresentação; não estou conseguindo usar o método `sleep`. Aparece uma `stage` em branco e depois a classe que contem a apresentação. Quero que apareça a janela de apresentação e depois a principal. Como fazer isso?

```
public static Stage WINDOWS;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = new FirstLayout().portal();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    WINDOWS = primaryStage;

    WINDOWS.setTitle("Memory Game");

    WINDOWS.setScene(scene);

    WINDOWS.show();

     try {
            //InputThread: nome do cenário que quero que apareça
            //inputThread: nome do método que traz o layout do cenário; 

        WINDOWS.setScene(new Scene(new InputThread().inputThread()));
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {} 

}
public static void main(String [] args){launch(args);}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é isso que você quer, mas tai:

```
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/** Example of displaying a splash page for a standalone JavaFX application */
public class TaskBasedSplash extends Application {
  private Pane splashLayout;
  private ProgressBar loadProgress;
  private Label progressText;
  private Stage mainStage;
  private static final int SPLASH_WIDTH = 676;
  private static final int SPLASH_HEIGHT = 227;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { launch(args); }

  @Override public void init() {
    ImageView splash = new ImageView(new Image("http://fxexperience.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/logo.png"));
    loadProgress = new ProgressBar();
    loadProgress.setPrefWidth(SPLASH_WIDTH - 20);
    progressText = new Label("Will find friends for peanuts . . .");
    splashLayout = new VBox();
    splashLayout.getChildren().addAll(splash, loadProgress, progressText);
    progressText.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    splashLayout.setStyle("-fx-padding: 5; -fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-border-width:5; -fx-border-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, chocolate, derive(chocolate, 50%));");
    splashLayout.setEffect(new DropShadow());
  }

  @Override public void start(final Stage initStage) throws Exception {
    final Task<ObservableList<String>> friendTask = new Task() {
      @Override protected ObservableList<String> call() throws InterruptedException {
        ObservableList<String> foundFriends = 
          FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<String> availableFriends = 
          FXCollections.observableArrayList("Fili", "Kili", "Oin", "Gloin", "Thorin", "Dwalin", "Balin", "Bifur", "Bofur", "Bombur", "Dori", "Nori", "Ori");

        updateMessage("Finding friends . . .");
        for (int i = 0; i < availableFriends.size(); i++) {
          Thread.sleep(400);
          updateProgress(i+1, availableFriends.size());
          String nextFriend = availableFriends.get(i);
          foundFriends.add(nextFriend);
          updateMessage("Finding friends . . . found " + nextFriend);
        }
        Thread.sleep(400);
        updateMessage("All friends found.");

        return foundFriends;
      }
    };

showSplash(initStage, friendTask);
new Thread(friendTask).start();
showMainStage(friendTask.valueProperty());
  }

  private void showMainStage(ReadOnlyObjectProperty<ObservableList<String>> friends) {
    mainStage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
    mainStage.setTitle("My Friends");
    mainStage.setIconified(true);
    mainStage.getIcons().add(new     Image("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Copenhagen/PNG/32/people.png"));

    final ListView<String> peopleView = new ListView<>();
    peopleView.itemsProperty().bind(friends);

    mainStage.setScene(new Scene(peopleView));
   mainStage.show();
  }

  private void showSplash(final Stage initStage, Task task) {
    progressText.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    loadProgress.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    task.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
      @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observableValue,     Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
          loadProgress.progressProperty().unbind();
          loadProgress.setProgress(1);
          mainStage.setIconified(false);
         initStage.toFront();
          FadeTransition fadeSplash = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1.2),         splashLayout);
          fadeSplash.setFromValue(1.0);
          fadeSplash.setToValue(0.0);
          fadeSplash.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
              initStage.hide();
            }
          });
          fadeSplash.play();
        } // todo add code to gracefully handle other task states.
      }
    });

Scene splashScene = new Scene(splashLayout);
initStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
final Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
initStage.setScene(splashScene);
initStage.setX(bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2 - SPLASH_WIDTH / 2);
initStage.setY(bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight() / 2 - SPLASH_HEIGHT / 2);
initStage.show();
  }
}
```

Explicando o que ela faz:

Imagem1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui o link: http://www.fxexperience.com/

Esse código cria um SplashScreen que é algo parecido com o que você disse, primeiro mostra uma tela de apresentação que na imagem é uma tela para carregar.

E depois de carregar mostra isso:

Imagem2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Explicando o código:

Na primeira imagem é carregado uma tela, que é uma imagem e um ProgressBar, isso é feito no método `showSplash`, que é onde se "liga" a barra de progresso com o Task, Task é a classe em que pode ser criada uma Thread, isso pode ser explicado nesse link: http://aprendendo-javafx.blogspot.com.br/2014/08/threads-e-javafx.html , Mas resumindo o JavaFX só cuida do layout e não tem outra thread para outras execuções.

No código é usado uma stage para criar tanto a tela de abertura(imagem1) quanto para criar a tela principal(imagem2).

O método `showMainStage` é o layout da imagem2.

O método `init` é o layout da imagem1.

E o `start` é onde vai ser iniciado o Task(Thread), determinado o tempo(Abaixo do progressbar é apresentado as linhas do `FXCollections...`):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < availableFriends.size(); i++) {
          Thread.sleep(400);
          updateProgress(i+1, availableFriends.size());
          String nextFriend = availableFriends.get(i);
          foundFriends.add(nextFriend);
          updateMessage("Finding friends . . . found " + nextFriend);
        }
        Thread.sleep(400);
```

E iniciado os outros métodos:

```
showSplash(initStage, friendTask);
new Thread(friendTask).start();
showMainStage(friendTask.valueProperty());
```

Espero ter ajudado.

---

Existe uma classe chamada `Service`, essa classe consegue separar as duas telas.

O código:

```
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/** Example of displaying a splash page for a standalone JavaFX application */
public class TaskBasedSplash extends Application {
  private Pane splashLayout;
  private ProgressBar loadProgress;
  private Label progressText;
  private Stage mainStage;
  private static final int SPLASH_WIDTH = 676;
  private static final int SPLASH_HEIGHT = 227;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { launch(args); }

      @Override 
      public void init() {
            ImageView splash = new ImageView(new Image("http://fxexperience.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/logo.png"));
            loadProgress = new ProgressBar();
            loadProgress.setPrefWidth(SPLASH_WIDTH - 20);
            progressText = new Label("Will find friends for peanuts . . .");
            splashLayout = new VBox();
            splashLayout.getChildren().addAll(splash, loadProgress, progressText);
            progressText.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            splashLayout.setStyle("-fx-padding: 5; -fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-border-width:5; -fx-border-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, chocolate, derive(chocolate, 50%));");
            splashLayout.setEffect(new DropShadow());
          }

      @Override 
      public void start(final Stage initStage) throws Exception {
          Service<ObservableList<String>> service = new Service<ObservableList<String>>(){ 
            @Override
            protected Task<ObservableList<String>> createTask(){
                  return new Task<ObservableList<String>>() {
                  @Override 
                  protected ObservableList<String> call() throws InterruptedException {
                    ObservableList<String> foundFriends = 
                      FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList();
                    ObservableList<String> availableFriends = 
                      FXCollections.observableArrayList("Fili", "Kili", "Oin", "Gloin", "Thorin", "Dwalin", "Balin", "Bifur", "Bofur", "Bombur", "Dori", "Nori", "Ori");

                    updateMessage("Finding friends . . .");
                    for (int i = 0; i < availableFriends.size(); i++) {
                      Thread.sleep(400);
                      updateProgress(i+1, availableFriends.size());
                      String nextFriend = availableFriends.get(i);
                      foundFriends.add(nextFriend);
                      updateMessage("Finding friends . . . found " + nextFriend);
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(400);
                    updateMessage("All friends found.");

                    return foundFriends;
                  }
                };
            }
          };

        service.start();
        service.setOnRunning((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
            showSplash(initStage, service); 
        });
        service.setOnSucceeded((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
            try {
                showMainStage(service.valueProperty());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

      }

      private void showMainStage(ReadOnlyObjectProperty<ObservableList<String>> service) throws InterruptedException {
        mainStage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        mainStage.setTitle("My Friends");
        mainStage.getIcons().add(new     Image("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Copenhagen/PNG/32/people.png"));

        final ListView<String> peopleView = new ListView<>();
        peopleView.itemsProperty().bind(service);

        mainStage.setScene(new Scene(peopleView));
        mainStage.show();
      }

      private void showSplash(final Stage initStage, Service<ObservableList<String>> service) {
        progressText.textProperty().bind(service.messageProperty());
        loadProgress.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
        service.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
          @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observableValue,     Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
              loadProgress.progressProperty().unbind();
              loadProgress.setProgress(1);
              initStage.toFront();
              FadeTransition fadeSplash = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1.2),         splashLayout);
              fadeSplash.setFromValue(1.0);
              fadeSplash.setToValue(0.0);
              fadeSplash.setOnFinished((asd) -> initStage.hide());
              fadeSplash.play();
            }
          }
        });

        Scene splashScene = new Scene(splashLayout);
        initStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        final Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
        initStage.setScene(splashScene);
        initStage.setX(bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2 - SPLASH_WIDTH / 2);
        initStage.setY(bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight() / 2 - SPLASH_HEIGHT / 2);
        initStage.show();
  }
}
```

As alterações que fiz foram nos métodos: `start`,`showSplash` e `showMainStage`.

Foi substituido o `Task<ObservableList<String>>` por `return new Task<...` dentro de um método criado dentro da classe Service.

Foi retirado o `mainStage.setIcofield(boolean)` para não minimizar a `Stage`.

E depois os métodos que chamavam o `Task` foram substituidos por `Service`.

Ela separa as duas telas quando é colocado a segunda tela dentro do `service.setOnSucceeded(...` do método `start`, e a primeira tela no `sercice.setOnRunning(...`.

Caso o tempo do desaparecimento da tela inicial for grande você pode mudar o número do `FadeTransition fadeSplash = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1.2),         splashLayout);` em `Duration.serconds`.

Espero ter Ajudado.

Comment: Editei a resposta, desculpe pela demora.

Comment: Nesse caso, você está minimizando o palco principal, em determinado tempo, para mostrar outro e depois maximizá-lo; mas quero que o palco principal seja mostrado só após o segundo palco sumir.

Comment: Em Swing ainda dava para fazer com um `setVisible(false)`, no JavaFX, você pode no lugar de `setIconfiet(false)` por `setOpacity(0.0)` e ele fica(ou deveria fiar) invisível, caso não funcione também tem no lugar `mainStage.close()` e depois no antes de inicializar o método `showMainStage()`(ou dentro no lugar do `setIconfiet(true)`) o `mainStage.show()`. Caso eu encontre outra solução melhor eu coloco.

Comment: Se encontrar, coloca o código, certo? Valeu!

Comment: Código Editado.

Comment: Deu certo? Se deu marca com correta.

Comment: Obrigado, Lucas... certíssimo!